# syntax error missing } after property list

Tags: javascript

my browser keeps shouting at me with the syntax error: missing } after property list, and I have no idea why. Here's the relevent code. Thanks in advance.

```
function addToDb()
{
    var source = "SoundCloud";
    var partyKey = "4";
    var id = "0987654321";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'connect.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {functionname: 'addSong', arguments: [id, source,partyKey]},
        success: window.alert("check your db"); //here I get the error
    });
};
```

Comment: Don't put a semicolon (;) inside an object literal (as on the success line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`success` should be a function.

```
  success: window.alert("check your db");
});
```

ought to be:

```
  success: function() { window.alert("check your db"); }
});
```